# Identify if miner is mining at all

Tags: miner-configuration, bfgminer

This is my first time to try to run bitcoin miner on my laptop (for testing), I used `bfgminer` and was able to run it however I'm not sure if its going anywhere:

```
 CPU 0:       |  1.27/ 1.28/ 0.00Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
 CPU 1:       |  1.16/ 1.27/ 0.00Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
 CPU 2:       |  0.94/ 1.18/ 0.00Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
 CPU 3:       |  1.16/ 1.20/ 0.00Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
```

What does this mean, my miner is not processing or mining as I can see its `0.00Mh/s`?

Comment: Do you have a debug log you can post somewhere. It looks like you are hashing at approx 1mh/s per core. That now days is slow, so it may be that you are hashing but it's hard for your computer to get a share. Also look on the pools stats page see if any shares show up

Answer (score -2):

If You are a beginner just starting you should probably go for GUIMINER or CGminer if you are planning on mining on your GPU if you are planning on mining on CPU you should probably go with pooler-cpuminer. BFGminer is meant for ASIC like USB Block erupters.

I HIGHLY ADVISE YOU **AGAINST** MINING ON YOUR LAPTOP AS THEY HAVE VERY BAD COOLING AND YOU CAN BURN YOUR MOTHERBOARD AND DESTROY IT IN MINUTES.

Comment: Arguments don't get better when capitalized.